# Self publish with Hebrew fonts

Tags: self-publishing, ebook, fonts

I am trying to self-publish my master's thesis which contains a decent bit of Hebrew. So far, I have tried Kindle Create, Vellum, and Apple Books for Authors, none of which seem to allow Hebrew fonts.

Any idea how to properly embed Hebrew fonts in the above-mentioned applications or an alternative self-publishing option?

Answer (score 2):

A pretty well-known self-publisher, BookBaby, has an option for publishing in Hebrew:
[BookBaby/Hebrew-Publishing](https://www.bookbaby.com/hebrew-publishing)

KDP has an option too, except it is only in paperback, ebooks are not available at this time:
[KDP/Hebrew, Yiddish-Publishing](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/GML3FXP998V8WS4U)

Comment: Thank you Nai54!

Comment: @Drytin Great! If it helped you, you can press the checkmark at the top left of my answer to mark it as accepted.